# Lifetime of rvalue bound to static const reference

Tags: c++, reference, temporary

Consider this:

```
std::string foo();

void bar() {
         const std::string& r1 = foo();
  static const std::string& r2 = foo();
}
```

I know that the lifetime of the string resulting from the first call to `foo()` will be extended to the lifetime of `r1`.

What about the temporary bound to `r2`, though? Will it live until the end of the scope or will it still be there when `bar()` is re-entered?

*Note:* I am not interested whether a particular compiler does so. (I am interested in the one we use, and I can test easily with that.) I want to know what the standard has to say on this.

Comment: Independently on the answer, this seems to be a bad coding style, so with good coding style the question should never arise.

Comment: @SergeRogatch You should rather say what to use instead.

Comment: @Melebius: Doing so would become possible only when the actual goal is stated.

Comment: This is completely trivial to test for yourself...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The temporary is extended to *the lifetime of the reference*.

> `[C++14: 12.2/5]:` **The temporary to which the reference is bound** or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound **persists for the lifetime of the reference except**:
>
> - A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s *ctor-initializer* (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits.
> - A temporary bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the *full-expression* containing the call.
> - The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) is not extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the *full-expression* in the return statement.
> - A temporary bound to a reference in a *new-initializer* (5.3.4) persists until the completion of the *full-expression* containing the *new-initializer*. *[ Example:*
>
>   ```
>   struct S { int mi; const std::pair<int,int>& mp; };
>   S a { 1, {2,3} };
>   S* p = new S{ 1, {2,3} }; // Creates dangling reference
>   ```
>
> *—end example ] [ Note:* This may introduce a dangling reference, and implementations are encouraged to issue a warning in such a case. *—end note ]*

<sup>(In particular, note that none of the bullet points match this scenario.)</sup>

So, in this case, it's essentially until the program ends.

We can, of course, test this pretty trivially:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Tracked
{
    Tracked() { std::cout << "ctor\n"; };
    Tracked(const Tracked&) { std::cout << "copy\n"; };
    ~Tracked() { std::cout << "dtor\n"; };
};

void foo()
{
    static const Tracked& ref = Tracked();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "main()\n";
    foo();
    std::cout << "bye\n";
}
```

Result:

> main()
>   ctor
>   bye
>   dtor

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68e18ca8a328ce95))